# How can I transfer files between a windows host machine and a linux docker image?

Tags: docker

I am running windows 10 and the most recent version of docker. I am trying to run a docker image and transfer files to and from the image.

I have tried using the "docker cp" command, but from what I've seen online, this does not appear to work for docker images. It only works for containers.

When searching for info on this topic, I have only seen responses dealing with containers, not for images.

Comment: When one runs a Docker image, it's instantiated in a container. I'm not really sure what you mean by wanting to copy content to a *running* Docker image, without copying to a container... whereas adding content to a *non-running* image is the job of adding an `ADD` or `COPY` command to its Dockerfile.

Comment: Right, I see. This clarification is what I was missing and couldn't find. A container is effectively a running instance of a docker image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docker image is basically a template used for containers. If you add something to the image it will show up in all of the containers. So if you just want to share a single set of files that don't change you can add the copy command to your docker file, and then run the new image and you'll find the container.

Another option is to use shared volumes. Shared volumes are basically folders that exist on both the host machine and the running docker container. If you move a file on the host system into that folder it will be available on the container (and if you put something from the container into the folder on the container side you can access it from the host side).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Understanding the difference between the image and the container is what I couldn't find.

Comment: Yeah it is a very common confusion point when people are first starting to work with docker- I'm glad I could help!